# Error installing npm package 'kurento-client' (BufferUtil ~ node-gyp rebuild)

Tags: javascript, node.js, kurento

I'm trying to install a package '**Kurento-client**' via npm but it gives error in installing its own dependencies `(bufferutil and utf-8-validate). Error also mentions 'node-gyp rebuild'`

Here is the screenshot of the error:
[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Can you please tell, what should I do or change?

**When I install those 2 dependencies separately (bufferuil and utf-8-validate), they install successfully with the latest version.**

**But the Kurento-client is installing their old version. I don't know why. I need only kurento-client to be installed.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for a while, I solved it by dropping the npm version. The reason is that some packages have dependencies which they need to install, and in our case, those dependencies were of the old version which cannot correlate with the newer version of npm. Either you have to update those ones separately or drop your npm version. Hope it helps someone!